# Linux man page terminology: `[.n]`?

Tags: manpage

In some man pages, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memchr.3.html, I see the following:

```
       void *memchr(const void s[.n], int c, size_t n);
```

What is the significance or interpretation of the `[.n]` term?

### update

As [sj95126](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13843268/sj95126) points out, this was well covered in [Linux memcpy restrict keyword syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035306/linux-memcpy-restrict-keyword-syntax).  This entry could be marked as a duplicate, though the subject line is substantially different.

Comment: The notation [.n] is used to indicate an optional feature or argument.

Comment: I think it indicates that the first n bytes are going to be accessed, n is the third argument

Comment: @normal not in this case

Comment: I think it is a way of expressing the semantic constraint that the function expects a pointer to an array of a certain size.

Comment: Mostly explained here: [Linux memcpy restrict keyword syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035306/linux-memcpy-restrict-keyword-syntax).

Answer (score -1):

I think the representation is too new, and maybe it has been used for 2-3 years. It denotes the dimensions of arrays or the size of the referenced object. I would expect it to be `const void * s`. Looking at [the commit change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=c64cd13e002561c6802c6a1a1a8a640f034fea70), by which I've learned that it is a kind of VLA syntax, we can see my expectation is not groundless. The documentation says

> The `memchr()` function scans the initial n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s for the first instance of c.